# Does this statement actually initialise the variable type in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing, static-typing

I am using python 3.7. I have the following line for typing;

```
from typing import List
ConnectionOptions = List[str]
```

Does it actually initialise `ConnectionOptions` as a list of string or is it merely for typing purposes for static checking?

Reason I ask is usually typing statement uses `:` but this one doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't create a list of strings. That creates a **type alias** - `ConnectionOptions` can now be used as an annotation meaning "list of strings".

If you want to create an empty list of strings, the way to do that is to use `[]`, and then not put anything but strings in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It corrected a serious misconception I had.

Am I right that all typing statements is to use `:`?